# Как написать маппер entity в dto (и обратно) для класса с коллекциями других entity?

Tags: java, entity, mapstruct, mapping

Как написать маппер entity в dto (и обратно) для класса с коллекциями других entity?
использую mapstruct и @Mapper
Все остальные поля нормально маппит, коллекцию нет.
entity классы

```
public class StudentEntity {
    private UUID id;
    private String surname;
    private List<MarkEntity> markEntityList;
    private List<SubjectEntity> subjectEntityList;
//конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры
}

public class MarkEntity {
    private UUID id;
    private int value;
    private SubjectEntity subjectEntity;
    private StudentEntity studentEntity;
//конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры
}

public class SubjectEntity {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private List<StudentEntity> studentEntitiesList;
    private List<MarkEntity> markEntitiesList;
//конструкторы, геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

В DTO такие же поля

```
public class StudentDTO {
    private UUID id;

    private String surname;

    private List<MarkDTO> markDtoList;

    private List<SubjectDTO> subjectDtoList;
}

@Mapper
    public interface StudentMapper {
    
    // работают нормалью
        StudentMapper INSTANCE= Mappers.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);
        StudentDTO toStudentDTO (StudentEntity studentEntity);
        StudentEntity toStudentEntity(StudentDTO studentDTO);
    
    //попытка написать маппер коллекции. не работает. коллекция markDtoList и subjectDtoList не мапится. 
        List<MarkDTO> toMarkDTOList(List<MarkEntity> list);
        List<MarkEntity> toMarkEntityList(List<MarkDTO> list);
        List<SubjectDTO> toSubjectEntityList(List<SubjectEntity> list);
        List<SubjectEntity> toSubjectDTOList(List<SubjectDTO> list);
    }
```

Comment: Если добавили в интерфейс коллекции, то должно все сработать, попробуйте перекомпилировать проект без ide. В реализации интерфейса должны появиться новые методы. Вопрос по поводу ссылок на объекты, в дто они должны остаться такие же как и в исходных объектах: `StudentEntity.subjectEntityList` взаимосвязаны с `SubjectEntity.studentEntitiesList` и ссылаются друг на друга? Тогда возможна рекурсия. Такой случай как нужно обрабатывать?